# Delaware tax free shopping

Tags: united-states, taxes, shopping, europe, tax-free-savings

I heard that Delaware is tax-free state.

If I'm not from US, do I have to pay some taxes when I buy some stuff (like iPad) in Delaware and come back to Europe?

Comment: What country are you taking stuff back to? I'm from the U.S. so my info is limited, but aren't VAT and related rules by country, not E.U.-wide?

Comment: To Poland, so EU country